# In Cakephp How to find related data between two tables

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 controllers

1. Customers
2. Tickets

Model Customer.php

```
public $hasMany = array(
        "Ticket" => array(
            'className' => 'Ticket',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
            )
        );
```

Now am trying to get the list of customers having `Ticket.status < 2`

And am trying this query in customer controller.

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'conditions' => array(
                        "OR"=>array(
                    "Customer.created  >"=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 month")),
                    "Ticket.status  <"=> 2,
                    )

                        ),
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'order' => array('Customer.created'=>'DESC')
                    );
```

But its not working.

Comment: Have a look http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: You need to understand the sql necessary to do what you want _first_. It's currently "not working" because there is no join from customers to tickets - so `WHERE Ticket.status < 2` is an sql error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    "Customer.created  >"=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 month")),
                   ),
                'contain' => array('Ticket' => array('conditions'=> array("Ticket.status  <" => 2))),
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'order' => array('Customer.created'=>'DESC')
                    );
```

Just try above query and share the results.

Comment: Its giving the same result, `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Ticket.status' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Bingo its working! But what if i want a list of customers from this months or customers having tickets status < 2. Like if i have an two month old customer  but having ticket open then i need all the customers from this month and also all the customers having open tickets.

Comment: Please elaborate more. I am not getting you brother.

Comment: Now am getting `List of customers created within this month and having tickets status < 2`.  But i need `List of customers created this month along with list of customers having tickets status < 2`. That is why i was using the `OR condition` in my above code.

Comment: In your situation I suppose you should read Joining Tables article from cakephp docs.